# Why is this meta content redirect not working

Tags: html, asp.net, redirect, iis

The default document for the IIS .Net project is a Default.htm file. The following code reflects the contents of the Default.htm file.

When it runs, it does not redirect to the Project1 folder, but looks for the Login.aspx in the current directory instead (example: www.website.com/Login.aspx when it should be  www.website.com/Project1/Login.aspx). I assumed my url tag was incorrect, however it is without flaw.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=Project1/Login.aspx">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Loading ...</p>
    <p>Please click <a href="Project1/Login.aspx">here</a> to login</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does it not look in the Project1 folder for the Login.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change to this (add slash at the beginning of url):

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/Project1/Login.aspx">
```

Comment: Thank you Victor, I appreciate your response. Unfortunately I have already tried that, and it doesn't work.